# c++ read access violation with extended classes

Tags: c++

As the title says when I run my program, visual studio, give me that error. The class that produce that error is the following:

```
class UsesScene {
    BaseScene & scene;
public:
    UsesScene(BaseScene& scene) : scene(scene) {}

    void Start() { scene.Start(); }
    void EventHandler(SDL_Event ev) { scene.EventHandler(ev); }
    void Update() { scene.Update(); }
    void Draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer) { scene.Draw(renderer); }

};
```

The popup appears after } at the end of the initialization of the Start void.

Another code that can interact with these classes is the following:

```
void GameManager::regScene(UsesScene scene) {
    if (display != NULL) {
        UsesScene* ptr = &scene;
        UsesScene** pptr = &ptr;
        display = *pptr;
    } 
    else
    {
        UsesScene* ptr = &scene;
        UsesScene** pptr = &ptr;
        buffer = *pptr;
    }
}
```

the display & buffer are declared as

```
class GameManager
{
private:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    UsesScene* display;
    UsesScene* buffer;
    bool isRunning;
    bool reStart;
};
```

and for access to the display or buffer's parameter I use the following syntax:

```
display->Start();
```

and the last thing that has to do with this class is this part of code:

```
TestScene tScene;
UsesScene testScene(tScene);
this->regScene(testScene);
```

Test Scene simply extends BaseScene:

```
class BaseScene
{
private:
    bool sceneloop = false;

public:
    virtual void Start() { std::cout << "BasceScene::Start()" << std::endl; };
    virtual void EventHandler(SDL_Event event) {};
    virtual void Update() {};
    virtual void Draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {};

    void _toggleLoopMode() { sceneloop = !sceneloop; }
    bool _sceneloop() { return sceneloop; }

};
```

How I can solve this?

ps:
some code that doesn't interfere with the Display and Buffer wasn't reported, if you need: free to ask

Comment: The code for `regScene` exhibits shades of pure madness. `scene` is a value argument whose lifetime ends on function exit. The `display` member is therefore set to the address of an expiring automatic variable, and any dereference thereafter invokes *undefined behavior*. Likewise for `buffer`.

Comment: I agree the usage of &  does not respect the lifetime of the variables involved.

Comment: Hemm so the problem is that I need to remove all that kind of stuff (pointer to pointer) and use the classic init like the generic setter elements? or I need to declare the buffer and display as a public variable?

Comment: @Pinnaker No, the problem is that `regScene()` takes its `scene` parameter **by value**, thus gets a **copy** of whatever `UsesScene` object is passed in to it, and so `display`/`buffer` are being set to point at a local object that gets destroyed when `regScene()` exits.  Pass the `scene` parameter **by reference** or **by pointer** instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a few hours of coding, thanks to Remy Lebeau, I've finally resolved this issue.

First I've changed the regScene() method and now looks like this:

```
void GameManager::regScene(UsersScene *scene) {
    if (SceneManager::_display == NULL)
        _display = scene;
    else
        _buffer = scene;
}
```

And then I pass the scene like this:

```
TestScene  tScene;
UsersScene testScene(tScene);
sManager->regScene(&testScene);
```

Thanks to all.